# Javascript.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to assign each of the divs a color in the array colors, using a for in

```js
var colors = ["#232323","#343434","#555555","#989889","#987898","#458676"]

var squares=document.querySelectorAll(".square")

for (i=0; i<squares.length; i++){
  squares[i].style.background=colors[i]
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.square {
  float : left;
  height: 30%;
  width:30%;
  background-color: red;
  margin : 1%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600p1%
```

```html
<iDOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Proyecto Color Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" align="center">

      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
</div>


<script src="Javascript.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the undefined error. Your code worked for me if I fixed the CSS for the `.container`. (As shown in the question it seems to include a typo and is incomplete, but if I gave it a specific height and width that seemed to let the percentage width for `.square` work.)

Comment: Give `.container` a height of 500px or something.

Answer (score 2):

Use devtools to view your HTML and styles. For instance, if you open the "Elements" tab, and click on `.container`, and in the inspector pane to the right choose "Computed", you will see the following:

[image]

The height is zero. that's because you haven't given the div any content that would cause it to have any non-zero height. To test this, simply add an element style such as `height: 500px`:

[image]

and you will see your results:

[image]

The style inspector will also show you the error in your `max-width` property (see the yellow triangle), so you should fix that too.

Moral of the story: Chrome provides great tools for debugging your code--CSS, HTML and JS. Learn them and use them. Fifty years after the heroines in [Hidden Figures](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4846340/) learned FORTRAN by reading the manual, reading the documentation remains the best way to learn new tools. Devtools has [excellent documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles) for its style inspector. Read it.

#### Your original error message

> Javascript.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

I'm confused by this error message. It implies that the `style` property did not exist on some DOM element, which should never be the case. Something else must be going on.

Comment: ty for your reply, i fixed that error, once i declare the variables before assigning them their value. , but super usefull that thing about devtools, already reading, ty very much

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct, but you aren't getting the results you want because your divs are empty. Try putting a little something in each one, like an `&nbsp;` and try. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/1eovkr5L/) a jsfiddle to show you what I mean.

Comment: The divs' `.square` class has a width and height specified, so it shouldn't matter if they are empty, should it? Except that the dimensions are percentages and their container's CSS is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You had some errors on your code.

I've done this code snippet.

Changes to your code:

- I've set 100x100px to the divs so your divs have some size and you can see the color. You can also add content to your divs so they'll have some size.
- You were missing } at the end of .container class
- I've set to 600px max-width on .container class

```js
var colors = ["#232323","#343434","#555555","#989889","#987898","#458676"]

var squares=document.querySelectorAll(".square")

for (i=0; i<squares.length; i++){
  squares[i].style.background=colors[i];
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.square {
  float : left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin : 1%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Proyecto Color Game</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" align="center">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be useful to the OP if you pointed out what are the changes you made and why.

Comment: well, @fahmir can compare codes and try to understand the fixes. if he/she doesn't understand something in it there is always the possibility to ask :)

Comment: *"@fahmir can compare codes"* - That's not very convenient for other people who happen upon this question, they'll have to scroll back and forth to see what you've done. And speaking of what you've done: changing `style.background` to `style.backgroundColor` is not necessary, it works either way, and what if the OP specifically wants the `30%` dimension on the squares?